# How to implode subarrays in a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, implode

I want to implode values in to a comma-separated string if they are an array:

I have the following array:

```
$my_array = [
    "keywords" => "test",
    "locationId" => [ 0 => "1", 1 => "2"],
    "industries" => "1"
];
```

To achieve this I have the following code:

```
foreach ($my_array as &$value)
    is_array($value) ? $value = implode(",", $value) : $value;
unset($value);
```

The above will also change the original array. Is there a more elegant way to create a new array that does the same as the above?

I mean, implode values if they are an array in a single line of code? perhaps `array_map()`? ...but then I would have to create another function.

Comment: Why must it be in a single line of code? Wouldn't it be better to have more verbose, more readable code?

Comment: The `&` operator does exactly that, [assign by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#example-97), so you are asking PHP explicitly to modify the original array. So, to begin with, you need to not use `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new array and set the elements (-;

```
<?php
...
$new_array = [];
foreach ($my_array as $key => $value)
     $new_array[$key] = is_array($value) ? implode(",", $value) : $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append values to new array:

```
$my_array = [
   "keywords" => "test",
   "locationId" => [ 0 => "1", 1 => "2"],
   "industries" => "1",
];
$new_Array = [];
foreach ($my_array as $value) {
    $new_Array[] = is_array($value) ? implode(",", $value) : $value;
}
print_r($new_Array);
```

And something that can be called a "one-liner"

```
$new_Array = array_reduce($my_array, function($t, $v) { $t[] = is_array($v) ? implode(",", $v) : $v; return $t; }, []);
```

Now compare both solutions and tell which is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write/iterate a conditional statement if you `type` the strings (non-arrays) as single-element arrays before imploding them.

With `array_map()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Tf9Gk))

```
$my_array = [
    "keywords" => "test",
    "locationId" => [ 0 => "1", 1 => "2"],
    "industries" => "1"
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            return implode(',', (array)$v);
        },
        $my_array
    )
);
```

Or from PHP7.4, `array_map()` with arrow function syntax: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RVXDo))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => implode(',', (array)$v), $my_array)
);
```

Or `array_walk()` and modification by reference ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2M2Hr))

```
array_walk(
    $my_array,
    function(&$v) {
        $v = implode(',', (array)$v);
    }
);
var_export($my_array);
```

Or a foreach loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2CWsm))

```
foreach ($my_array as &$v) {
    $v = implode(',', (array)$v);
}
var_export($my_array);
```

All snippets will output:

```
array (
  'keywords' => 'test',
  'locationId' => '1,2',
  'industries' => '1',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array( 'key1' => array( 'one', 'key2' => array( 'two', 
'three' ) ), 'four', 'five' );
$finalData = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $arr,
    function( $subArr ) use ( &$finalData ) {
            $finalData[] = $subArr;
    }
);
$str = is_array( $finalData ) ? implode( ",", $finalData ) : $finalData;
print_r( $str ); // one,two,three,four,five
```