# Add value from one element to other in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer I needed, maybe my wording is wrong.
Anyway, I have a two-dimensional array with hundreds of values, what I need is to insert a value from second element to the first element.

Example;

1. I have four elements in an array:

   ```
   [0] = 1, [1] = 9, [2] = 9, [3] =5
   ```
2. I need to put these into a single element, so that it would turn
   into    this: `[0] = 1995.`

I have a feeling there might be something I could do with foreach, if so, maybe someone can explain to me, in detail, how that would exactly work?
OR
Maybe there's a function I'm not aware of.

Comment: how about `implode()`?

Comment: You can use implode.

$array = array_map(function($r){ return implode('',$r); },$array);

Comment: "to insert a value from second element to the first element". Not sure that your example fits to this description. Could you provide better example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implode subarrays in a 2-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253716/how-to-implode-subarrays-in-a-2-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following, using [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$arr = [1, 9, 9, 5];
$val = implode($arr);
unset($arr);
$arr[0] = $val;
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/VTb7vO

To use the solution using `implode` on the whole multidimensional array, you can use the following:

```
$arr = [[1, 9, 9, 5], [1, 9, 9, 6], [1, 9, 9, 7], [1, 9, 9, 8]];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $val = implode($value);
    $arr[$key] = $val;
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/X6vueO

another, much shorter solution could be the following:

```
$arr = [[1, 9, 9, 5], [1, 9, 9, 6], [1, 9, 9, 7], [1, 9, 9, 8]];
$arr = array_map('implode', $arr);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/0ju8he

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate each inner array of numbers you can use `implode` on each of it.

```
$newArray = array_map('implode', $array);
```

If it is executed on the array `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 1, 1]]` it will create the array `['123', '13', '111']`. [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b72d592a2677a066b4d3b02125c065d7c7b3f0de)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [2,3,4];
$var = implode($arr, '');
var_dump( $var );
```

Two dimensional:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array(22,18),
  array(15,13),
  array(5,2),
  array(17,15)
  );

foreach ($cars as $val) {
    $var1 = implode($val, '');
    var_dump( $var1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var= "";
foreach($arr as $element) {
    $var .= $element; 
}
```

Comment: Even for low-hanging fruit questions, all answers should explain how and why the posted method works.  Never post code-only answers.