# Using json_decode to format data output

Tags: php, arrays, json

The data returned by an API is in this format

```
[{"name":"Agnes ","amount":"40000"},{"name":"John","amount":"35000"},{"name":"Joyce","amount":"50000"},{"name":"Peter","value":"45000"}]
```

I want to re-format that output so that it looks like this:
Agnes-40000, John-35000, Joyce-50000, Peter-45000
So, I wrote something like this, letting $data represent the returned data above;

```
$new = json_decode($data);
     
     foreach ($new as $key => $jsons) { 
     foreach($new as $key => $value) {
         echo $value; 
         echo ",";
    }
}
```

But the output I get is like:  Agnes,40000, John,35000, Joyce,50000, Peter,45000
How do I write the javascript to display the data like
**Agnes-40000, John-35000, Joyce-50000, Peter-45000**

Comment: Do you want a JavaScript or PHP answer?

Comment: I just wondered that myself...

Comment: If php, then here's a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253716/how-to-implode-subarrays-in-a-2-dimensional-array  otherwise this question is Unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of objects. You need to concatenate the `name` and `value` properties.

```
$array = json_decode($data);
foreach ($array as $el) {
    echo "{$el->name}-{$el->value},";
}
```

Comment: Then the server response will be broken, no?

Comment: I think the server should not adjust responses for the client if the client can bring the data into the desired format

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. The PHP code is just displaying the response from the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonFromServer = '[{"name":"Agnes ","amount":"40000"},{"name":"John","amount":"35000"},{"name":"Joyce","amount":"50000"},{"name":"Peter","value":"45000"}]';

var json = JSON.parse(jsonFromServer);
var arrResult = []; // if array
//var textResult = ''; // if string

if(json && json.length){
    for(var j = 0, jLen = json.length; j < jLen; j++){
        var obIn = Object.values(json[j]);
        
        var map = obIn.map(function(el){
          return el.trim();
        }); 
        
        var res = map.join('-');
        
        arrResult.push(res);
        //textResult += res;
    };
};

console.log(arrResult); // if array
//console.log(textResult); // if string
```

console result   ["Agnes-40000", "John-35000", "Joyce-50000", "Peter-45000"]